# Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler not effective

Tags: kubernetes

On my EKS cluster running K8s v1.20 and autoscaler v1.16 I see several nodes that are running at less than 20% CPU and less than 60% memory. I don't understand why the autoscaler does not consolidate pods from a few of those nodes and schedule them on some other nodes that are equally loaded, so as to better utilize all nodes.

I'd expect to see all nodes either in "I'm almost full in CPU" or "I'm almost full in memory" state, or both. Instead out of the 29 nodes in the nodegroup about 17 are below 60% memory and below 20% CPU. It seems pods from about 5 of those nodes could move to the remaining 12 nodes, freeing up 5 nodes.

Comment: Can you share `cluster-autoscaler` pod logs? Is there any PDB (pod distribution budget) active in your environment? Also please use autoscaler version `v1.20` because it's recommended that `cluster-autoscaler` version should be in parallel with EKS version.

Comment: Where is the logs I couldn't see them

Comment: Yes indeed, there are lots of PDBs with Min_available=1, max_unavailable=n/a, and Allowed-disruptions=0. Perhaps this is the problem....  Here is a log sample   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r716HNbTrlTVYG93i8gxJwUphg7OumVC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey, you have 2 node group, one of the them has reached the min size (3 nodes) and other one using the memory, it's not about HPA because your nodes using the memory and all of them are above the limit. Logs are showing this.

Comment: Please explain again, I cannot understand what you are saying. All the nodes are above the limit? What limit? What do you see in the logs exactly? Also, if the PDB does not allow ANY disruptions, doesn't this stop the autoscaler from moving pods around?

Comment: In your logs there are lines like `Node ip-10-65-60-199.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not suitable for removal - memory utilization too big (0.602710)` this means, `Node utilization level, defined as sum of requested resources divided by capacity, below which a node can be considered for scale down`, In your deployments, if your resource `requests` are too high, cluster autoscaler thinks it's being used. this value can be configured by `scale-down-utilization-threshold` parameter. Please look at the config options, I think there is a misconfiguration here without researching enough.